# Calling apex method with AuraEnabled in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I need to call an apex method from a class I don't have access to modify and mark it @auraEnabled. I know it's generally not supported as per documentation. But through imperative apex, is it possible to do in any way where we can call apex method without any @AuraEnabled.

Comment: probably by proxy. I.e. creating a new class with an `@AuraEnabled` method that you can call, which in turn calls the thing you can't modify.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call an apex without annotating an apex method with @AuraEnabled.
You can always create your own custom apex with @AuraEnabled method which in turn calls the method you originally intended to.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void yourMethod(){
  ClassYouCannotChange.method();
}
```